# How to upload large file on Colab Pro

Tags: google-colaboratory

I recently purchased Colab Pro.
My allocated VM shows around 120 GB of disk space. However, when I try to upload a file (80 GB) in size, the upload doesn't complete and it shows a red circle in the bottom:

[image]

Any ideas, on what could be the problem?

Comment: I've had this issue before at solved it by uploading the file to Google Drive and mounting the drive